# How to start background script in lua

Tags: lua

I have a script that's time critical. To speed up things I made a separate script that contains the code that is not time critical. In my main (time critical) script I want to start the non time critical script at the end before it returns nil. How do I start the second script without waiting on it? This without stopping the second script when returning nil in the first script.

Comment: Lua threads are cooperative; if you want to run a script in the background you will have to run it in a separate `lua_State` on a different operating system thread/process. This is almost entirely a C programming problem that is unrelated to the use of Lua.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`io.popen`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-io.popen) to start a new process (implemented in any language) and read its output when you are ready.

Comment: But this will make my time critical script wait on my non-critical script? Or am I wrong about this?

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Will dive into the documentation. Thanks again!